# Flutter TextField change Icon color when selected

Tags: flutter, dart

Goal: Changing the color of the `prefixIcon` next to the `TextField` when clicking on the `TextField`.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
    hintText: 'Username'
  )
)
```

Comment: You should post the segment of code that you are working with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per flutter's update, accentColor property has been deprecated.

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties

OLD:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  accentColor: Colors.blue,
),
```

NEW:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
    secondary: Colors.blue,
  ),
),
```

Comment: @SalahAdDin Maybe you didn't update to the latest version of flutter.

Comment: with the last version the disabled color is based on the `OnSurface` color, which is a different one.

Comment: But this changes icon's color in every state. What if I just want to change color only when input is focused and revert to grey when blurred?

Comment: for me primary color worked

Answer (score 21):

When Selected the color shown is app `primaryColor:` of Theme.

One Way of changing is using `Theme` Widget.

```
 Theme(
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                  labelText: "Email",
                                  hintText: "example@mail.com",
                                ),
                                autofocus: true,
                              ),
                              data: Theme.of(context)
                                  .copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.redAccent,),
                            ),
```

Other is to change `primaryColor` at `MaterialApp` Theme level.

Comment: it worked for me, but I used `accentColor:` instead of `primaryColor:`, seems that they changed the source color

Answer (score 13):

In Flutter 2.5, you can set the active color of the icon in [`ColorScheme.primary`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html):

```dart
theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
  colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
    primary: Colors.green,
  ),
),
```

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=786c3bbbb0e13030085cde01400bcebe&null_safety=true)

Comment: Only thing worked for me. THANKS;

Comment: Yeah same here. Thanks @NearHuscarl

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to change the whole app theme just for 1 behavior of the field, you can use MaterialStateColor class from dart and switch colors based of the state.

Here is an example

```
InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: widget.icon,
        prefixIconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
            states.contains(MaterialState.focused)
                ? Colors.black
                : Colors.grey)
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to use `MaterialStateColor.resolveWith()` directly for `Icon(color:` property, but it turned out that `prefixIconColor` is the only right place to do that

Answer (score 3):

Convert StatefulWidget in state class create FocusNodes and use TextFormField

```
 List<FocusNode> _focusNodes = [
  FocusNode(),
  FocusNode(),
];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNodes.forEach((node){
    node.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  });
    super.initState();
  }


TextFormField(
            focusNode: _focusNodes[0],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.alternate_email,
                  color: _focusNodes[0].hasFocus ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                ),
                hintText: "Email"),
          ),
```

Comment: make sure subscribe to focus changes and call setSate there to reflect the state correctly. also dont forget to unsubscribe and dispose... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344456/6543507

Comment: Thank you so much, it solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve that with

```
ThemeData(
   colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
              primary:Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

inside MaterialApp or you add Theme on your TextFormField

```
Theme(
    data:Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
              primary:Colors.red,
        ),
       ),
    child:TextFormField()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just specify `prefixIconColor` property in `inputDecoration`. If it's not specified then it will take `MaterialStatProperty` by `Default`.

Here is Example

```
TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search,),
              prefixIconColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by modifying the `accentColor` property at the `MaterialApp` Theme level.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a ColorScheme with fromSeed Color inside your MaterialApp.

```
Color primaryAccentColor = const Color(0xFF4D70FF);

MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: primaryAccentColor),
          ),
    ...
);
```