# Flutter TextFormField Prefix Icon Focus Color on Theme Change

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I have a TextFormField, which contains a prefix Icon that I would like to turn red when it is focused on.

[image: Unfocused]

To achieve that, I have wrapped the TextFormField with a Theme object ([Relevant SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802765/flutter-textfield-change-icon-color-when-selected)):

```
 Theme(data:ThemeData(colorScheme:
                    ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(primary:Colors.red)),
                    child: TextFormField()
```

[image: Red focused color]

This works great, but the problem arises when I switch to Dark mode inside my application.
Because I am using this setting (***I am assuming***), it turns the entire TextFormField to use the primary color which is black and then the entire TextFormField is black.

[image: Dark mode]

Other TextFormField elements which I have not wrapped with a Theme object, are styled correctly according to theme.

[image: Dark mode other textformfield]

**How would I go about fixing this?**

What I would like to achieve is have the TextFormField appear like the others in Dark mode and be highlighted red when it is focused on, regardless of light or dark mode.

Would I need to define a custom application theme for this?

Answer (score 0):

Tru to inherit from current theme by using `copyWith` method:

```
Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      primaryColor: Colors.red
    ),
      child: TextFormField(),
  )
```

**UPDATE**

Or alternatively, you can try using `darkTheme` property of the `MaterialApp` widget:

```
MaterialApp(
  darkTheme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(...),
  home: ...
)
```

Comment: I already have copyWith in the code snippet I shared in my question. How is this different?

Comment: It also does not work.

Comment: did you try to specify darkTheme property?

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what you mean.