# How to know if TextField is active in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextField` in my app, I want to enable a `FloatingActionButton` whenever user taps to the textfield (that is to say starts typing).

Is there a way I can track whether user is on the textfield and typing?

Comment: Does it answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341856/how-to-detect-when-a-textfield-is-selected-in-flutter

Comment: definitely! appreciated