# How to convert Latin letters from keyboard to Thaana Unicode in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm building an application with my native language in Flutter However, my language (Dhivehi used in Maldives) is not a supported language in the Flutter localization package.

I have tried to add it as a new language using a localization package, but I was not able to do it.

In my application there is a TextField where users have to type in Dhivehi letters (Thaana) so they can search for contents within the app. How do I convert Latin letters from the keyboard to [Thaana Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaana_(Unicode_block)) in my flutter application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert Latin letters to [Thaana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaana) letters or you can create your own custom keyboard.

### Converting Latin to Thaana

You can use the `onChanged` parameter of `TextField` to get the current input and then use a loop with a `Map` or `switch` statement to convert the Latin text to Thaana.

This is a rough example:

```dart
String _latinToThaana(String latinText) {
  final thaana = StringBuffer();
  for (var codeUnit in latinText.codeUnits) {
    final latinChar = String.fromCharCode(codeUnit);
    if (latinChar == 'a') {
      thaana.write('އަ‎');
    } else if (latinChar == 'b') {
      thaana.write('ބ‎');
    }
  }
  return thaana.toString();
}
```

Using a long if-else chain surely isn't the best way to do it, but it shows one way to start. This particular method wouldn't handle double letter combinations very well, though.

Another way might be to do a search and replace:

```dart
String _latinToThaana(String latinText) {
  latinText
      .replaceAll('aa', 'އާ')
      .replaceAll('a', 'އަ‎')
      .replaceAll('b', 'ބ');
}
```

As long as you replace the doubles before the singles that should work.

### Custom keyboard

Alternately, you can create an in-app keyboard with the characters and layout that you need. You can check out the Mongolian keyboard [here](https://github.com/suragch/mongol) as a reference.

If you only want to show the keyboard when the `TextField` has focus, you can listen for changes in the focus. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344456/3681880).

Comment: Thank you, can you tell more about Converting Latin to Thaana? I have tried implementing a custom keyboard, problem is now it is shown always on the screen, how can I call the keyboard only when clicked on TextField?