# How to get state of TextFormField or its current border color in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

How to get current state of the TextFormField like if it has error or it has focus or it doesn't have focus.
What I want to achieve is that I have a suffix icon Widget (not Icon widget type, any widget) and I want to change its stroke color to match TextFormField's border's color. Even if I can't get the state of TextFormField, I want to get its current border color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76451853/how-to-change-textformfield-background-color-when-focus/76451989#76451989


and:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341856/how-to-detect-when-a-textfield-is-selected-in-flutter

Comment: @MendelG I know about the focus node but it can only tell you the focus state. What about the error state of TextFormField ?