# Flutter Keyboard makes textfield hide

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I've added a form with a text field and when I clicked the textfield and keyboard comes, the textfield goes up.

This is my code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
return new Scaffold(
  body:  new Container(
      color: Colors.purple,
      constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0, bottom: mediaQuery.viewInsets.bottom, ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                  Text(
                    'What is your Business Name?',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                  ),
                  AppForm(),
                ],
              ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0, bottom: mediaQuery.viewInsets.bottom),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
              color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the result without opening the keyboard: 
[Image without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVXpt.png)

This is the image after opening the keyboard:
[Image after opening the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4yjh.png)

---

Here is my flutter doctor output.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√] Flutter 
(Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165], locale 
en-US) [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
28.0.0) [√] Android Studio (version 3.1) [!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 
1.25.1) [!] Connected devices ! No devices available ! Doctor found issues in 
2 categories.
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of flutter? What does `flutter doctor` say?

Comment: Here is my flutter doctor output.                                                                                     Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.25.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: I'd recommend you to go to the channel flutter master `flutter channel master` which is currently at `v5.7` and also clean your project with `flutter clean` and `Invalidate caches and restart`

Comment: Seen this ??  https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-4-ensure-a-textfield-or-textformfield-is-visible-in-the-viewport-when-has-the-focus/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This was the case with me . You are definitely wrapping a scaffold inside another scaffold . there should be only one scaffold widget inside your flutter app i.e the main layout . Simple remove all the ancestor scaffolds you have and keep only one scaffold . dont wrap a scaffold into another scaffold .inspite of that you can wrap a scaffold inside a container .

Make sure in your main.dart file you are not doing this :-

✖✖

```
return Scaffold(
body : YourNewFileName(),
);
```

Inspite of the above code do this:-
✔✔

```
return YourNewFileName();
```

Comment: @Nirodya Gamage can you post the main.dart file so that i can check where the error is ??

Comment: I'm so sorry you are correct! I found another Scaffold on a backdrop. I removed one and it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: great . Coz that same thing happened to me and this was how i solved it .

Comment: I have scaffhold inside scaffhold. It requires for me to add Tabbarview. What is the solution for it.

Comment: Tab bar can be added with a single Scaffold too @dominic_torreto. 
As of now having scaffold inside scaffold with give you some errors like this one. so u should change the structure with which u r designing your app .

Comment: Yes. Changed the structure. Eventhough its not working.

Comment: Same, I can see that there is only one `Scaffold` in widget tree from `Flutter DevTools` and the problem still exists. Btw I thought `Scaffold` can be present in every page, no?

Answer (score 51):

```dart
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    // ...
    appBar: AppBar(
      // ...
    ),
)
```

Fixed problem textfield was hidden by keyboard

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I saw many answers saying to set up this property as `false`, but actually is the value `true` that makes it work as desired. o/

Comment: Somehow i follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551390/9039350) and its the false one that fix the problem..

Answer (score 30):

This answer is not specific the question above but may be useful to those who are still having issues with the keyboard covering the selected text field, no matter what they do. I got to this page while trying to resolve such an issue.

Prior to the problem I had been making some changes to try and improve my splash screen on app startup. As per someone's recommendation, I had included the following line in the `<resources><style>` section of the styles.xml file in the android/app/src/main/res/values folder

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

This had the unexpected effect of stopping any fields scrolling up in the main app when the keyboard is displayed. This might be obvious to some, but it wasn't to me.

Hope this info helps someone.

Comment: This fixes this issue but brings other issues if you have a top banner. The status bar is displaying (that's one) and it does it on top of the banner

Answer (score 26):

You can simply wrap the widget you want to never be hidden by the keyboard inside a padding, like follow :

```
Padding(
         child: YourWidget()
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(
         bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom));
```

Answer (score 15):

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is Deprecated
use instead `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`

Comment: This works awesome. Setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` for the Scaffold will adjust the view to be within the area above your keyboard with this.

Comment: resizeToAvoidBottomInset is true by default. no need to add that one

Answer (score 14):

If you use [ScreenUtilInit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package then maybe setting `useInheritedMediaQuery: true` in the constructor of `ScreenUtilInit` will help you. It helped me :)

Comment: For me, it worked when commenting the line `useInheritedMediaQuery: true1 in the material app

Comment: This answer was a life saver

Comment: HOLY SHOOT I thought this was gonna take me hours but, thank you, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Anybody with an explanation why ?

Comment: This should be highlighted somehow because it saves a lot of time !! Thank you !

Answer (score 12):

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Removing above line from

`android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

made my app fixed to input field auto scroll upwards to come in view able on keyboards opens

thanks @GrahamD

[image]

Comment: I had this issue, too. This line was added as a result of using the flutter_native_splash package. Don't think I would have ever found that. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem because of flutter_native_splash

Comment: This fixes this issue but brings other issues if you have a top banner. The status bar is displaying (that's one) and it does it on top of the banner

Answer (score 12):

You should add `SingleChildScroolView` into your Scaffold and add `reverse: true` into your SingleChildScroolView

```
Scaffold(
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          child: Container()));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me (

Comment: @OlegYablokov could you please share your code so I can inspect it.

Comment: I have already solved the problem and posted an answer on this page, but thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Just cut and paste your body code in this -

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
              // your body code 
           ],
         ),
       ),
```

had the same issue got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215917/2884893)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `Scaffold` than wrap the body with `SingleChildScrollView`

for Example like this:

```
...
return Scaffold(
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(),
        TextField(),
        TextField(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
...
```

this was really a lifesaver for me.
Now the scaffold will become scrollable.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using scroll padding on the Textfield

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Demo SoftKeyboard"),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
          TextField(
            scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:40), // THIS SHOULD SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM
        ),                
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: It works when I use `MaterialApp` in my `main.dart`, but not when I use `MaterialApp.router` (or maybe there is another problem). Do you think you know why?

Answer (score 3):

resizeToAvoidBottomInset is true by default.

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   );
```

I set it to false and it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

I also faced with this issue. This's my solution:

1/ Wrap the Column Widget (content of Dialog) inside the Padding Widget with property `padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,)`

2/ Wrap all widgets above inside `SingleChildScrollView`

Below is full code for my Dialog:

```
Future<T?> showDialogLikeBorrowBook<T>(
 BuildContext context, {
 bool barrierDismissible = true,
 required String labelDialog,
 required String labelMainButton,
 required Widget contentDialog,
 required Function() onTap,
 }) async {
       return await showGeneralDialog(
       context: context,
       barrierLabel: "barrierLabel",
       barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
       barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
       transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
       transitionBuilder: (_, anim1, __, child) {
              return ScaleTransition(
              scale: Tween<double>(
              begin: 0.0,
              end: 1.0,
              ).animate(
                  CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: anim1,
                  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                  ),
                 ),
            child: child,
          );
         },
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
       return Material(
       type: MaterialType.transparency,
       child: Align(
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       child: Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: R.dimens.mediumSpacing1)
            .copyWith(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top, // This attribute used to make sure the Dialog widget always show below the AppBar/StatusBar 
                                                       //if the Dialog widget has size with height large more normal size when the keyboard be shown
        ),
         child: GestureDetector(
           onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()); // Wrap Dialog widget inside Gesture Detector to every time the user tap outside the TextField widget but still inside scope of Dialog widget,
                                                              //the FocusNode of TextField will be unfocus 
          },
           child: Container(
             constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: double.infinity),
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius:
                   BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(R.dimens.smallRadius)),
               color: Colors.white,
             ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(R.dimens.mediumSpacing),
              child: _ShowContentDialog(
               labelDialog: labelDialog,
               labelMainButton: labelMainButton,
               contentDialog: contentDialog,
               onTap: onTap,
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   },
 );
}

class _ShowContentDialog extends StatelessWidget {
 const _ShowContentDialog();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SingleChildScrollView(
   physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
   child: Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(
       bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom, // This attribute will auto scale size of Column widget when the keyboard showed
     ),
     child: Column(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       children: [
           _renderLabelDialog(),
           ... something widget,
           CustomTextField(
              labelTextField: "Ghi chú",
              hintText: "Nhập ghi chú",
              textInputType: TextInputType.text,
              maxLines: 4,
              textController: _editNoteController,
             ),
           _renderButton(context),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

**Dialog without the keyboard**

[image: Dialog without the keyboard]

**Dialog with the keyboard when touch on the TextField widget**

[image: Dialog with the keyboard when touch on the TextField widget]

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem today and using `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` and `SingleChildScrollView` solved my problem.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("TitleBar"),
  ),
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ... some widgets here...
    ,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the entire widget in a Scaffold, then all other widgets contained in a SingleChildScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

If your content is scrollable but you are not using Scaffold like the other answers mentioned this is the solution I have used

```
SizedBox(height: (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0) ? 200 : 16)
```

You can change the `200` and `16` value to some other convenient value as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was similar to GrahamD's answer.

I was declaring my own theme using a parent that had .Fullscreen, for example:

```
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

[I've raised an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59397) with the Flutter team because it should be possible to use a Fullscreen theme and have normal Chat app behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue by adding a `Stack()` as the body of my `Scaffold()`, this allows the `TextField()` object to slide up above the soft keyboard. Initially I used `SingleChildScrollView()` for the body which resulted in the `TextField()` objects being obscured by the soft keyboard.

Solution that worked for me:

```
child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the flutter updates(2021), "resizeToAvoidBottomInset:true" gives a yellow-black strip error when keyboard appears.

This is how I fixed the above issue:

1. Inside build() method, check if keyboard is open, ***bool keyboardIsOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0*;**
2. Set ***resizeToAvoidBottomInset:true*** inside Scaffold
3. Wrap your widget with a SizedBox() and set height like this:  ***height: keyboardIsOpen
   ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2
   : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,***

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, to prevent from this problem - Flutter Keyboard makes `TextField` hidden – we can do an easy job. We have to Wrap the `TextFields` with  `SingleChildScrollView` as a widget for body argument in Scaffold. Only use `SingleChildScrollView` in that place. If you did not do so, it would not work well. For instance:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("App"),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.blue,
            elevation: 5,
            child: Text()
          ),
        ),
        TextField(),
        TextField(),

      ],
```

Also, there is another way do this. In the above code, you can replace Column with `ListView` Widget like the below code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("App"),
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: 300,
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.blue,
            elevation: 5,
            child: Text(),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(),
        TextField(),

      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **complete example** which dynamically updates the padding:

[image: before and after keyboard is shown]

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class KeyboardPaddingTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const KeyboardPaddingTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _KeyboardPaddingTestState createState() => _KeyboardPaddingTestState();
}

class _KeyboardPaddingTestState extends State<KeyboardPaddingTest> {
  EdgeInsets _viewInsets = EdgeInsets.zero;
  SingletonFlutterWindow? window;
  final _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    window = WidgetsBinding.instance?.window;
    window?.onMetricsChanged = () {
      setState(() {
        final window = this.window;
        if (window != null) {
          _viewInsets = EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(
            window.viewInsets,
            window.devicePixelRatio,
          ).add(EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(
            window.padding,
            window.devicePixelRatio,
          )) as EdgeInsets;
        }
      });
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.greenAccent[100],
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _viewInsets.bottom),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[100],
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textFieldController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Tap to show keyboard',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              'Testing Keyboard',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to do not remove those two lines from AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I did this mistake, all my SingleChildScrollView were not working and the keyboard was hidding the textfield of all my form.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
Scaffold(
    **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,**
    appBar: AppBar(
      // ...
    ),
)
```

One thing to note is if you have Scaffold or any kind of Scaffold like AutoTabsScaffold on the parent widget you should this prop **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,** to all of the Scaffold.

Comment: The answer needs to be in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If the textfield gets hidden by the opening of keyboard, Here is the simplest solution of all .

```dart
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Login User"),
          SizedBox(
            height: 48,
          ),
          Focus(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter your email"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can simply wrap the `TextField` with `Focus` Widget it will solve the textfield hidden issue for better.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem i also used `SingleChildScrollView` but that doesn't solved my problem.

My problem was accruing in this code.

```
   Stack(
      childern:[
           SingleChildScrollView(),// In scollView i have textFeild when keyboard opens doneButton hide the textFeild.
           doneButtonWidget()//this button align with the bottom of the screen. 
   ]
)
```

To Solve the problem i follow this and it solved my problem.

```
    Column(
       childern:[
            Expaned(  
                child:SingleChildScrollView(),// In scollView i have textFeild when keyboard opens doneButton hide the textFeild.
               flex:1
              ),
              doneButtonWidget()//this button align with the bottom of the screen. 
             ]
          )
```