# Keyboard hides TextField in a PageView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a quite complex screen with a page view and a `FutureBuilder`. In the Pagebuilder I also have a `TextFormField`, when I now click into the text field the keyboard opens like expected. But it then hides the textfield and a button below the text field.
I already searched for solutions, things i tried:

- setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to true
- putting the outer column or the pageview into a `SingleChildScrollView`
- adding some padding (in the size of the keyboard) to the bottom

Any other ideas?

I only have ONE Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

What approach are you using to get the keyboard size? The best approach is to add a bottom padding that pushes the textfield upwards, you might also want to put the form fields inside the `SingleChildScrollView` that you've mentioned:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But this also does not work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: It might seem a strange question but have you implemented a splash screen for your app? Also, is this on android or ios, or both?

Comment: Yes, I have native splash screens for both ios and android. The bug (as described) appears also on ios and android (both simulated and on real devices)

Comment: Sorry, only just seen your reply. I had an issue on Android caused by splash but not ios. Still, have a look at this post and my answer as well as others. It may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335483/flutter-keyboard-makes-textfield-hide/56394951#56394951

Answer (score 0):

Make your page scrollable and add padding to the button like so:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
      children: 
         textInput,
         Padding(padding: ..., child: button) 
             ...
```

This would allow user to scroll to the button after edit.

Another solution is to make button float - it would always be above keyboard

```
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  children: [textInput]
                    ..add(Container(
                      height: 1111, // button heigh, so could scroll underlapping area
                    )))),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: button,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: I tried your first solution, it does not change anything. To clearify: My main problem is that the keyboard hides the textfield.

Comment: What flutter version are u using?

Comment: Channel stable, v1.17.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

You should wrap your page with **SingleChildScrollView** so that you get scrolling in the case when your content grows bigger than the device height because of introduction of keyboard.

> Soution

1)Use of **WidgetsBindingObserver** mixin

2)Adding **scrollController** to **SingleChildScrollView**

3)Listening the event of presence of keyboard using **didChangeMetrics** and scrolling as per the need.

```
class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> with WidgetsBindingObserver{

ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    _scrollController.jumpTo(200); //as per your need
  }
```

Inside Scaffold widget adding controller to SingleChildScrollView

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
    )
```