# Login and register page doesn't scroll when keyboard is active, flutter application

Tags: android, flutter

Please I need your help I have a mobile application, when am typing on the input fields, the keyboard covers the input fields and it doesn't scroll for user to input text. See below the code am talking about. Below is a sample could you tell where the issue is ? (Note this is a flutter app)

```
AppTextField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      focus: emailFocus,
                      textFieldType: TextFieldType.EMAIL,
                      decoration: inputDecoration(context, hint: appLocalization.translate('email')),
                      nextFocus: widget.phoneNumber != null ? null : passFocus,
                      errorThisFieldRequired: appLocalization.translate('field_Required'),
                      errorInvalidEmail: appLocalization.translate('email_Validation'),
                      maxLines: 1,
                      cursorColor: colorPrimary,
                    ).paddingBottom(16),
```

Comment: use SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: **true**,
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Form(
```

This solution worked for me, by changing the value to true from my the code above. It was set to **false**.

N:B - I got the info from another thread. check the link some options there might also be helpful should incase any come across same issue.

[Flutter Keyboard makes textfield hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335483/flutter-keyboard-makes-textfield-hide?rq=1)