# Keyboard hide the textfield : SingleChildScrollView does not work

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textfield, singlechildscrollview

I am desperate to resolve this issue.

I made this simple page...

```
 return Scaffold(
      body:SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Column(children: [
          TextField(),
          TextField(),
          TextField(),
          SizedBox(height:200),
          TextField(),
          TextField(),
          TextField(),
        ],)
      )
    );
```

...and I tried all solutions from this post : [Flutter TextFormField hidden by keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335483/flutter-keyboard-makes-textfield-hide)

Adding this property to my Scaffold :

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false (or true)
```

Wrap the column with a bottom padding :

```
Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.only(bottom:MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), child:Column(),
```

Removing this line from styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Is there any angel who can help me ? Can the problem come from elsewhere like manifest... I was not having this issue before, now I have it on all my forms !

Comment: you have to warp column widget with padding widget, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I already tried :(

Comment: Is it added inside an alert dialog or bottom sheet?

Comment: @KaushikChandru No, it is not, it is called with Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(...

Comment: maybe its better to run `flutter clean` or upgrade version of flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from my AndroidManifest.xml. These two lines were missing.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I removed it previously myself because I had this warning : "Attribute hardwareAccelerated is only used in API level 11 and higher (current min is 1)"