# Keyboard covers TextField in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, scroll, keyboard

I have the problem that whenever I want to type something into my Textfield, the Keyboard covers it. 
I expected the screen to just scroll up whenever the keyboard appears. Any thoughts on that?
I tried to set resizeToAvoidBottomInsert to true and also to wrap everything into a SingleChildScrollView().

Here is my code:

```
  class PhoneNrInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController phoneNrController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode phoneNrFocusNode = FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 5)],
              color: Color(0xff05111f),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        //Textfield
                        child: TextField(
                          focusNode: phoneNrFocusNode,
                          autofocus: false,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            filled: true,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                            ),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            hintText: "Telefonnummer",
                          ),
                          controller: phoneNrController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    height: 40,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      ),
                      child: Text("Registrieren"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check this answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When i select a Textfield the keyboard moves over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it)

Comment: @LonelyWolf Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway. I'd like to understand why the approaches I tried doesn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else has the same issue:
I had included the following line in the  section of the styles.xml file in the android/app/src/main/res/values folder:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

That caused the problem.