# Flutter: The keyboard covers TextFields

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that shows textfields and image and I face a problem when the user tries to enter data in textfield as the keyboard goes up and cover the entire textfields.

I tried to use SingleChildScrollView but it is not practical as the textfields do not go up automatically but the user has to scroll up by himself.

Here is the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Animation and move up your text field when keyboard appears. Check this out [When i select a Textfield the keyboard moves over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it)

Comment: Thanks @Anas Mohammed I think it is the only way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a sized container inside, follow the below :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ... your code
          ]
        )
)
```

In your Scaffold, set resizeToAvoidBottomPadding property to false.

Comment: @AlexAli just updated answer, can you try that change

Comment: Thank you @gg11.. but still, the same problem persists after setting resizeToAvoidBottomPadding property to false.