# SingleChildScrollView obscured by custom keyboard

Tags: flutter, listview

Using `flutter 1.20.4`
I'm trying to implement a custom digit keyboard (a simple container at the bottom), which should appear into view when tapping on one of the rows in the List.

Here a small snippet of how I do it:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BudgetPageState budgetPageState = Provider.of<BudgetPageState>(context, listen: true);
    ButtonDial buttonDial =
        budgetPageState.showButtonDial ? ButtonDial() : null;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Budget Page"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: CustomList()),
          if (buttonDial != null) buttonDial
        ]));
  }
}
```

**However, when the keyboard appears, the bottom rows get obscured by the container.**
I tried using `Scrollable.ensureVisible`, that works for the middle rows, but the last ones are still obscured. It seems like the ScrollView still has it's old size (full height) when `Scrollable.ensureVisible()` kicks in (I notice this by looking at the ScrollBar).

Code snippet:

```
Scrollable.ensureVisible(context, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), alignment: 0.5);
```

See video below.

[Keyboard obscures last rows when tapped (here clicking on row 14)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BquDs.gif)

However, once the keyboard is up, the SingleChildScrollView has shrunk to the new size and the Scrollable now works.
[When keyboard is up, Scrollable.ensureVisible() does its job(here clicking on row 6 and 12)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niZkd.gif)

I know this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it), but

1. I tried multiple things of this issue.
2. I use a "custom keyboard"
3. The flutter github issue here below fixed this (I think)

Read through [this popular Flutter Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15983), this made me use `SingleChildScrollView` instead of `ListView`.

Tried [this](https://medium.com/@5lineofcode/flutter-fix-textformfield-textarea-textfield-hidden-by-keyboard-3d5613136aad), this fixes the keyboard obscuring the bottom Rows by shifting them up, however now when clicking on the first Rows, they get moved out of view.

Tried [KeyboardAvoider](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_avoider), but as this is not an onscreen Keyboard, I doesn't work.

You'll find a full minimal reproducible example here below.

### main.dart

(Main  + ChangeNotifierProvider for the state)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollTest/budgetPage.dart';
import 'package:scrollTest/budgetPageState.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(HomeScreen());
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => BudgetPageState(), child: BudgetPage()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### budgetPage.dart

(Main Page with the `CustomList()` and the `buttonDial` (custom keyboard, here just a simple container)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollTest/budgetPageState.dart';
import 'package:scrollTest/customList.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class BudgetPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BudgetPageState budgetPageState = Provider.of<BudgetPageState>(context, listen: true);
    ButtonDial buttonDial =
        budgetPageState.showButtonDial ? ButtonDial() : null;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Budget Page"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: CustomList()),
          if (buttonDial != null) buttonDial
        ]));
  }
}

class ButtonDial extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### customList.dart

(Simple List view `SingleChildScrollView` and a `ScrollController`)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollTest/CustomRow.dart';

class CustomList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomListState createState() => _CustomListState();
}

class _CustomListState extends State<CustomList> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: _buildList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> _buildList() {
  List<Widget> widgetList = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    widgetList.add(CustomRow(rowID: i));
  }
  return widgetList;
}
```

### customRow.dart

(This is where I scroll to the selected row in `handleOnTap`)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollTest/budgetPageState.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class CustomRow extends StatefulWidget {
  final int rowID;
  CustomRow({Key key, @required this.rowID}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomRowState createState() => _CustomRowState();
}

class _CustomRowState extends State<CustomRow> {
  BudgetPageState budgetPageState;

  void handleOnTap(BuildContext context) {
    if (!budgetPageState.isSelected(widget.rowID)) {
      Scrollable.ensureVisible(context, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), alignment: 0.5);
    }
    budgetPageState.toggleButtonDial(widget.rowID);
    budgetPageState.updateIsSelected(widget.rowID);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    budgetPageState = Provider.of<BudgetPageState>(context, listen: false);
    budgetPageState.insertRowInHashMap(widget.rowID);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap:() => handleOnTap(context),
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: budgetPageState.isSelected(widget.rowID)
            ? Colors.grey[200]
            : Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Test ${widget.rowID}",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### budgetPageState.dart

(The state managed using `ChangeNotifier`. Mainly contains logic for selecting/deselecting a row as well as logic for when to show the keyboard (using `bool showButtonDial` and `notifyListeners()`)

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BudgetPageState extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool showButtonDial = false;
  Map<int, bool> _isSelectedMap = HashMap();
  int selectedId = -1;

  bool isSelected(int rowId) {
    return this._isSelectedMap[rowId];
  }

  Map<int, bool> get isSelectedMap => _isSelectedMap;

  void updateIsSelected(int rowId) async {
    ///Select the row [rowId] if we tapped on a different one than the one
    ///that is currently highlighted ([selectedId])
    ///The same row was tapped, we remove the highlight i.e. we don't
    ///put it back to [true]

    //Unselect all
    _isSelectedMap.forEach((k, v) => _isSelectedMap[k] = false);
    
     if (selectedId != rowId) {
      this._isSelectedMap[rowId] = true;
      selectedId = rowId;
    } else {
      selectedId = -1;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleButtonDial(int rowId) {
    if (!showButtonDial) {
      showButtonDial = true;
    } else if (rowId == selectedId) {
      showButtonDial = false;
    }
  }

  void insertRowInHashMap(int subcatId) {
    this._isSelectedMap[subcatId] = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: what is the placement of the custom keyboard? is it a flutter widget? what do you mean by "custom". this is clearly a margin calculation issues, I propose you try to solve it manually, by setting a maximum height for the keyboard and adding that as a bottom margin for the singelChildview

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime In it's most basic form it is just a `Container` widget.
I tried 
```flutter
      child: SingleChildScrollView(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: anySelected ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3 : 0),
child : ...,
)
```
but again, it doesn't work for the first tap, but for every subsequent tap I have a huge padding inside my List.