# When I click text field, Keyboard hides textform

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard, android-emulator, flutter-layout

If I press the textfield, I hope the comment box will come up on the keyboard.
It works in an emulator, but it doesn't come up if i use an android device.

this I want and It works in an emulator
[image]

this is in android device,  The comment box is hiding behind keyboard.

[image]

I already tried the method of MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom and
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true.

But it didn't work.
I don't know why it works on emulators and not on devices.

This is my code,
please help me.

```
SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () {},
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  _content(),
                  Positioned(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                      child: _commentBox()),
                  WaitingStreamBuilder(_waitingController),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it) out, pretty sure it's the same issue

Comment: Use SingleChildScrollView() as parent.

Comment: I've tried this when you use a stack widget the position if the textfield may change . So, It's better to use a 'List view' or 'SingleChildScrollView'