# Flutter TextFormField hidden by keyboard

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

**NOTE: Im using Navigator.of(context).push to push ModalRoute,**

Hi I have page with `ModalRoute` with `TextFormField` in the body, but when keyboard show up, the input is being hide by keyboard, how to fix this?

[image]

```
return Container(
      child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            //other widget
            SizedBox(height: _qtyAnimation.value),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Jumlah",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 145.0,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    focusNode: _qtyFocusNode,
                    controller: qty,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      prefixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.1),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
    );
```

thats my code, i try with focusnode and more, still same result
please help me

Comment: You can use FocusNode to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide on screen keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it)

Comment: its not work for me, already test that link,

Comment: My solution [here at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857184/8138591) solves this problem. It's very short and simple, no animation required.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

thanks solve my problem with this padding on bottom of textfield

```
    Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.only(
             bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom));
```

and mare reverse list

Comment: Great solution! :)

Comment: Great solution indeed! Thx.

Answer (score 69):

This worked for me...

First add this

```
final bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
```

Then use a SingleChildScrollView() to wrap around the main widget (whatever you're using, e.g. Column, ListView, etc) like this...

You need "reverse: true"

```
Widget build{
return Scaffold(
body: SingleChildScrollView(
reverse: true;
child: Container(...
```

You also need these two lines of code for the Scaffold as well..

```
return Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
body: SingleChildScrollView(...
```

and finally, reference the 'bottom' for your EdgeInsets..

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
reverse: true,
child: Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
child: Container(...
```

Comment: `padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom)` throw an error: bottom must be a constant... how do you fix this?

Comment: Fabio you add`'final bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;` 
after 
`Widget _body(WriteReviewModel model) {`

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me when composing a expanded multiline textfield in the bottom o a column, with ConstrainedBox and SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: On applying the above solution:  The TextFormField which is already above the keyboard on gaining the focus it moves upwards and is not visible in the screen. Ideally it should stays there only only the below screen TextFormField should scroll up

Answer (score 20):

You need to wrap everything in a **SingleChildScrollView** and set the **reverse** to true.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   reverse: true,
   child: Container(),
);
```

Just that worked for me!

Comment: This is the simplest solution if your content does not scroll by default (without the keyboard showing up). Indeed if your content is larger than the screen height, it will always be scrolled to the bottom, even without keyboard. That may not be what you want.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. I try all solution, but didn't work.
Finally I removed

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

from my styles.xml file in android folder, and fix the problem.

Comment: For me this is working in debug build, but in release build keyboard just coming up and hiding immediately, please confirm if this is the case for anyone?

Comment: No problem, it works fine both in debug and release. 
You must have another additional configuration that causes this. Try in clean project.

Answer (score 10):

There are few methods for this (as of Dec 3<sup>rd</sup> 2018):

You can read this for a better solution: [When i select a Textfield the keyboard moves over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it).

Inside `Scaffold()` add: [`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html).

You can also wrap your `TextWidget` with [`SingleChildScrollView()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html). This will allow you to scroll whenever the keyboard is shown.

Comment: not work for me, my textfield is inside row and sizebox

Comment: https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-4-ensure-a-textfield-or-textformfield-is-visible-in-the-viewport-when-has-the-focus/

Answer (score 4):

Set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false` inside your `Scaffold` Widget.

Note that `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` will be deprecated.

```
Scaffold( resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, ...)
```

Comment: It took me way too long to learn about `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`. Every time I used a flex layout, my keyboards would break. It was awful.

Answer (score 4):

I use form elements in modal_bottom_sheet plugin. I solved it by just adding the following code to SingleChildScrollView.

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)
```

Comment: This did not change the issue for me

Answer (score 4):

Too add to the commonly accepted answers here which is

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          child: Container(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.loose,
              children: <Widget>[
```

I added a thing to the bottom inset to prevent it from going too high.

```
    var bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
bottom = max(min(bottom, 80), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was combining the docs with tips over here. It uses, LayoutBuilder, SingleChildScrollView, Padding (with bottom hack) and finally, ConstrainedBox (to use Expanded). By combining these It works with Expanded widgets inside Columns.

The docs (from where LayoutBuilder comes):
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Structure

```
 return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,`
```

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: LayoutBuilder(builder:
              (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              reverse: true,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                      maxHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight),
                  child: Column(
```

Comment: Hmm this case worked just out of the box on beta channel for me

Answer (score 2):

It's **simple**, forget about those complicated answers. You just need to use the `scrollPadding` method that's available in `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
      scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200),
),
```

Comment: this is perfect

Answer (score 1):

SingleChildScrollView does solve the problem while the resizeToAvoidBottomInset is set to true, while setting it to false would be a not recommended solution. Let me explain why:

When user presses the TextField, usually a virtual keyboard will popup and takes up a large portion of the bottom space on the screen. In such case, problem would occur, if the TextField is near said bottom, it will be covered by the keyboard (resizeToAvoid... set to false), and user will be unable to see what they've typed in; if there are other widgets below the TextField (when resizeToAvoid is true, e.g. buttons in the same Column with TextField), there will be overflow because there is no space for them to show on the remaining viewport.

Speaking from a user's perspective, what we want is:

1. TextField who gets focus is always visible.
2. No bottom overflow and bugged graphics.

However, such description is not technical, it does not tell us how exactly do we implement it. What we actually want is, make the whole layout scrollable, and allow Scaffold to resize. When the viewport resizes, anything below the focused TextField scrolls away to the invisible bottom, and the TextField itself snaps to the keyboard.That's why SingleChildScrollView + resize = true is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

To have a centered content first on build method I added this:

```
final bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
```

and return this:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            ///Content
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                reverse: true,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      MyContent()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ///Button
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: MyBottomButton()
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And it works very well with keyboard flow

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was were important to use only small padding, otherwise when open the keyboard it makes a big mess.

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)
```

Check my solution:

```
child: Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.black,
       child: SingleChildScrollView(
         reverse: true,
          child: Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: Container(
              child: ReservationCard(
                ),
                  ),
                   ),
                    ),
                     )
```

Answer (score -2):

For Android, check for windowSoftInputMode. (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

[image: ScreenShoot AndroidManifest.xml]