# Hide/Dismiss keyboard on ListView scroll in Flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout

I have chat window in Flutter app.
Messages are presented as widgets inside `ListView` widget and I also have widget for message input attached to bottom of the window.

I want to

1. hide keyboard when I scroll the `ListView`
2. scroll to last message when new is added from `InputWidget`

code:

```
class _MessagesPageState extends State<MessagesPage> {
  final ScrollController listScrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ....
    body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              controller: listScrollController
              ....
          ),
          InputWidget()]
    );
}

class InputWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

....
Row (
  children: [
    TextField(
     controller: _textEditingController
    ), 
    IconButton(icon: ...., onPressed: (){})
  ]
 )}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to point 1 of you question :

You can create a listener function for `listScrollController` containing a call to an anonymous `FocusNode` (idea taken from this highly voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview)), and when any scroll event occurs, focus will be taken from your `TextField` and keyboard will be dismissed:

```
 class _MessagesPageState extends State<MessagesPage> {

 final ScrollController listScrollController = ScrollController();

 @override
 void initState() {
   listScrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
   super.initState();
 }

 _scrollListener() {
   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   ....
   body: Stack(
    children: [
      ListView.builder(
          controller: listScrollController
          ....
      ),
      InputWidget(controller: listScrollController)]
   );
}
```

Point 2 :

You'll notice that I modified your `InputWidget` to take a `ScrollController` as a parameter, so you can pass your `ListView` controller to it. and when the `IconButton` is pressed, `listScrollController` will jump to the end as you desire.

```
 class InputWidget extends StatelessWidget {

 InputWidget({Key key,this.controller}) : super(key: key);

 final ScrollController controller ;

 final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

 ....
 Row (
  children: [
    TextField(
      controller: _textEditingController
    ), 
    IconButton(icon: ...., onPressed: (){
      controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
    })
  ]
 )}
```

Comment: thank you, it seem that it works as expected! I now realized that when keyboard is shown some of messages are overflowed by keyboard, so I need to scroll my ListView accordingly?

Comment: Not at all ! by the way I tested the code before posting.

Comment: Can you recommend something for question in comment?

Comment: which kind of overflow ? can you explain ?

Comment: Some messages that were seen without keyboard are now hidden behind shown keyboard. So when keyboard appears I need to move messages up

Comment: You can refer to this solution to modify your `ListView` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586892/flutter-textformfield-hidden-by-keyboard

Answer (score 8):

For hiding keyboard on listview scrolling, you simply add *keyboardDismissBehavior* to it. Example

```
ListView(
 keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
 children: [],
)
```

Comment: beautiful, who needs a scrollController when you've got a one liner

Answer (score 3):

it's easy..Follow these step..

1. Change class to `StatefullWidget`
2. create `final ScrollController listScrollController = ScrollController();`
3. ListView should be like this:

   ```
        ListView.builder(
             controller: listScrollController,
             reverse: true,
   ```
4. If you use firebase change order by like this:

   `.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)`
5. Add this code in your Send button

`listScrollController.animateTo(0.0,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);`

**Automatically scroll up your textField, Add your `textField` and `ListView` inside `Stack`**