# How to create always visible button which doesn't cover up textField

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I want to create a submitting button which will be always visible and above the keyboard.
I tried to figure out that problem by several ways, such us using floating action button, bottom sheet, scroll padding or column with calculating size of button and column with another content size.
When I calculated height manually problematic were very small and large devices.
On the other hand when I tried to use floating button or bottom sheet, button cover up focused text field and error message from this textfield.

cover up textfield error text

[image: cover up textfield error text]

cover up part of textfield

[image: cover up part of textfield]

My goal is creating a button which will be visible above the keyboard all the time and won't cover up any part of textfield.

My actual code:

```
class KeyboardAvoidingViewport extends StatelessWidget {
  final PreferredSizeWidget? appBar;
  final List<Widget> bodyListWidget;
  final Widget floatingMemeButton;
  final bool isKeyboardVisible;

  const KeyboardAvoidingViewport({
    Key? key,
    this.appBar,
    required this.bodyListWidget,
    required this.floatingCustomButton,
    required this.isKeyboardVisible,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        body: SizedBox(
          height: isKeyboardVisible
              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                  MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom -
                  2 * Dimens.xxxl
              : null,
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: Dimens.m,
                vertical: Dimens.xxxl,
              ),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: bodyListWidget),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
          reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          child: isKeyboardVisible
              ? SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 2 * Dimens.m,
                  child: floatingCustomButton,
                )
              : null,
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I edited and added a code :)

Comment: Can you include `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,` on scaffold and rebuild the app.

Comment: I tried, but this didnt solve a problem.

Comment: are you using a single scaffold for full page?

Comment: Yes.
I tried option with 2 scaffolds, but it doesnt work too.

Comment: well you need to have single scaffold which is ok, Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53586892/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

I guess floating actin button will work perfect here, you said you tried it what went wrong there?

Edit:

You can try -

```
return Scaffold(
    body: // Your body
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.check),
  ), 
)
```

Comment: In scrollable widget when you tap on text field you are automatic focused on that. That behavior is good and I want it.
But when you use Floating Action Button, then focused text field is cover up by them.

Comment: the floating action button is on the right hand side by default and relatively small how does it covers the textfield?

Comment: this button is reusable in my application, so it have to be wider