# Keyboard Hiding TextFormField behind

Tags: flutter

keyboard appear on TextFormField

```
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
           backgroundColor: Colors.white,
           body: SingleChildScrollView(    
       ),
     );
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter TextFormField hidden by keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586892/flutter-textformfield-hidden-by-keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in scaffold resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true

```
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,//  
    body:   Container(),
 );
}
```