# Flutter/Dart Scrolling textfield above keyboard

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using textfields, how can I make it so it scrolls up a bit when entering email  and password?

Here is a preview of the code

https://pastebin.com/4EngQDV5

```
blank
```

Comment: But where are those textfields located? can you show what you have till now.

Comment: @Hosar, I added a preview of the code, code may be a bit messy but you may take a look thx.

Comment: You should keep the code in the question for future references.

Comment: My solution [here at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857184/8138591) solves this problem. It's very short and simple, no animation required.

Answer (score 38):

There is the solution which gave the expected outcomes in my case. TextField has a property calling **scrollPadding**.
`scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:40),`
By default it is set to `EdgeInsets.all(20.0)`

You can give a fixed value or use viewInsets.
Hope this will help you too.
Please find more information on this [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/scrollPadding.html).

Answer (score 25):

I found a nice solution.
I have added to the `TextFormField` the
`scrollPadding` property as follows

```
child: TextFormField(
        scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + fontSize*4),
        validator: _validator,
        cursorColor: cTextRegularColor,
        controller: _controller,
        obscureText: _obscure,
        obscuringCharacter: '*',
        textAlign: _textAlign,
        keyboardType: _input,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: cTextRegularColor,
          fontSize: fontSize,
        ),
```

By setting the bottomInset, in my forms, whenever the user taps on a TextField in the form, it does not only scroll down, it also shows the next TextField in the form, so the user does not need to scroll after s/he finished filling the current field.

Obviously, when the user will tap the next field in the form, the screen will scroll again, and again, show the next field,

I figured out that in long forms (more than 5 fields), the user does not need to scroll at all.

Comment: How to get back to actual state when we close soft keyboard again ? as it is keep showing scrolled position after closing it how to get back to normal state again ?

Answer (score 21):

Ok first, the code you pasted is incomplete, so I'm guessing you are having those textfields insides a Column. You have two options:
1st) In your Scaffold you can set this property to false like **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,** 
2o) You can use a **SingleChildScrollView** that will move up your textfield when the keyboard appears eg.:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: MyLoginPage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyLoginPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyLoginPageState createState() => _MyLoginPageState();
}

class _MyLoginPageState extends State<MyLoginPage> {
  String _email;
  String _password;
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final emailField = TextField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidEnvelope),
          hintText: "Email",
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[300], width: 32.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(97.0))),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _email = value;
        });
      },
    );
    final passwordField = TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.key),
          hintText: "Password",
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[300], width: 32.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0))),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _password = value;
        });
      },
    );

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.yellow[300],
            height: 300.0,
          ),
          emailField,
          passwordField
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Just copy and paste the code, and see if it's what you want.
Hope this help.

Comment: I tried this solution. But after typing, It cannot be scrolled upward, Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 10):

I using flutter 2.2.0 and when I add **SingleChildScrollView** it auto scroll up if keyboard show and overlap the textfield. **resizeToAvoidBottomInset** default **true** allow this function (tested on iOS). if you want the Textfield have more space with keyboard let try answer of **Varsik Nikoyan**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088995/12970517

hope can help.

Answer (score 4):

I actually had the same problem. Figured that you need to wrap the TextForms into a ListView to make it work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollView extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
// TODO: implement createState
return _ScrollViewState();
}
}

class _ScrollViewState extends State<ScrollView>{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: userInputBackgroundColor,
    body: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
               TextForm(),
               TextForm()
              ]
          ),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use textfield only, you can take a look at my code in og post.

Answer (score 0):

It is new code. I think this one help you. Add this code after the passwordField declaration.

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        emailField,
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        passwordField,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I tried this on a new page but it all appears in the top of the screen, how can I position the textfields?

Comment: I changed the code. please add this code after your final passwordField declaration